# How to make ALL elements have a transition effect

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want all CSS changes to have a transition. I tried

```
* { transition: all 1s; }
```

but it's not working.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3kpyxh/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your media query rules are ill-formed. Try this instead:

```
* {
    transition: all 1s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .special {
        padding: 30px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .special {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

The `padding` value is animated, but if you want the border to animate too, you would be better off changing the second `border` rule to `border: 1px solid transparent;`.

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3kpyxh/1/)